# Is it possible to add subtitles of a figure which contains subfigures

Tags: graphics, floats, subfloats

I have a single image which contains two sub-images. I want the following subtitles (a) and (b) to be shown correctly.
[image]

In which, left sides is my current image which contains two rectangular. And right sides is my expected result. I found a solution is that we can use `subfig` package. However, it requires separating the original figure into two subfigure. In that question, I am regarding that we do not need split original figure, I want to write (a),(b) directly below figure. Thanks
Current solution is

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\captionsetup{labelfont={bf}}
  \centering
    \subfloat[]{\centering\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{Fig1a.png}} \\
    \subfloat[]{\centering\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{Fig1b.png}}
  \caption{This is main figure}
  \label{fig:9}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion would be to clip the image contents within LaTeX; [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) allows for that:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \setbox1=\hbox{\includegraphics{example-image-a}}%
  \subcaptionbox{}{\centering\includegraphics[scale=0.5,viewport=.5\wd1 0 \wd1 \ht1,clip]{example-image-a}}%
  \qquad
  \setbox1=\hbox{\includegraphics{example-image-b}}%
  \subcaptionbox{}{\centering\includegraphics[scale=0.5,viewport=0 0 .5\wd1 \ht1,clip]{example-image-b}}
  \caption{This is main figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I've used `example-image-a` and `example-image-b` (from [`mwe`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mwe)) above, although you will use the same image. As such, you'll only need to capture the image in box 1 once. Note how the image is split in half (at the `.5\wd1` mark) with the `viewport` and `clip` combination.

Additionally, I've used [`subcaption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/subcaption), but you can manage the same with [`subfig`](http://ctan.org/pkg/subfig).

---

Here is an example of breaking up a single image into six equal parts (perhaps synonymous to your situation):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \setbox1=\hbox{\includegraphics{example-image}}%
  \subcaptionbox{}{\centering\includegraphics[scale=0.5,viewport=0 0 .16667\wd1 \ht1,clip]{example-image}}%
  \quad
  \subcaptionbox{}{\centering\includegraphics[scale=0.5,viewport=.16667\wd1 0 .3333\wd1 \ht1,clip]{example-image}}%
  \quad
  \subcaptionbox{}{\centering\includegraphics[scale=0.5,viewport=.3333\wd1 0 .5\wd1 \ht1,clip]{example-image}}%
  \quad
  \subcaptionbox{}{\centering\includegraphics[scale=0.5,viewport=.5\wd1 0 .66667\wd1 \ht1,clip]{example-image}}%
  \quad
  \subcaptionbox{}{\centering\includegraphics[scale=0.5,viewport=.6667\wd1 0 .8333\wd1 \ht1,clip]{example-image}}%
  \quad
  \subcaptionbox{}{\centering\includegraphics[scale=0.5,viewport=.8333\wd1 0 \wd1 \ht1,clip]{example-image}}%
  \caption{This is main figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Each component is extracted as a sixth of the total width `\wd1`, one step at a time.

Comment: So, If my figure have 5 rectangular. I want to subcaption as (a),(b),(c),(d),(e),(f). How to chose the  split value. I tried .2\wd1 but it did not work

Comment: @user8430: So you have a single image containing 6 pictures?

Comment: Yes sir. It has 6 pic in one figure.

Comment: Your way for splitting a single image in several sub-figures is awesome ! Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

```
\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
\includegraphics{zzz}\\
\hspace{1cm}(a)\hspace{2cm}(b)
\end{tabular}
```

Adjust the lengths to fit.

Comment: Thank your solution. I tested it but the margin top between (a),(b) so big. Do we have option to reduce it. And how to crate a main caption for that figure

Comment: `\\[-10pt]` will reduce the vertical space and just use `\caption{}` as normal after this tabular for any main caption