# Add subfigure captions to single figure

Tags: floats, subfloats

I have a single .png file that contains 4 figures (images) uniformly located on it. I would like to have a subfigure letter for each of them ( (a),(b),(c),(d) ), but I would like to avoid manually separating the figure in 4.

Is there a way to include a line below a single figure with (a),(b),(c),(d) between the figure  and the caption? Best possible case by choosing the location of these letters so I can adjust them as pleased.

Comment: You can `trim` and `clip` the PNG to extract out the four images. Is this what you mention you are *not* interested in?

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/260775/how-to-place-text-over-an-image?s=4|1.1867

Comment: Related: [Is it possible to add subtitles of a figure which contains subfigures](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/277220/5764)

Comment: @Werner I might be interested in that, if its done programatically yes.  However, some of them have not the same width, so it has to be tuneable. I will have a look at the suggestions, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you could use `tikz` with `onimage` to use to the `tikzonimage` environment.  Here's what I did to introduce text above an image (called imagefile).

```
    \documentclass{article}   

    \usepackage{onimage}            
    \usepackage{tikz}   

    \begin{document}

    \begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzonimage}[width=0.7\textwidth]{imagefile}
    \node at (0.10, 1.10) {(a)};
    \node at (0.50, 1.10) {(b)};
    \end{tikzonimage}
    \label{fig:blah}
    \end{figure}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) It'd be better if you complete your code with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`.

Comment: Hi! thanks for the response.  I can't seem to be able to find the `onimage` package (its not even in CTAN). Is there an alternative using some more "standard" package?

Comment: @Ander, you are right about it not in CTAN.  Here's some info about how to get it (and more importantly, to use it). http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/30435